# Eclipse RCP app leaking native memory on Linux only

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, memory-leaks, rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application leaking **native** memory. This happens on Linux only, the same application on macOS runs fine for a long period of time.

- Heap memory usage is OK, it's used quite intensively, but stays between bounds
- Linux RES mem usage increases slowly, VIRT increases less frequently, but more importantly. App crashes after 1 or 2 days, no error message, it looks like its killed by the OS
- Target platform is equivalent on Linux & macOS, except for the `org.eclipse.swt` plugin (3.5 on Linux, 3.1 on Mac)
- JVM is Oracle 1.6, tried an IBM JVM, tried on Java 7 & 8, no success
- Independant of the distribution, leak happened on SLES, but also on CentOS & Ubuntu
- Eclipse RCP version is 3.5
- no DirectBuffer used
- no nio class used
- no threads leak (cfr screendump)
- turned of JNI => grows slower, but still
- tried different garbage collectors, no success
- tried setting the env var MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=4, no success
- pmap does not show anything interesting, loaded libs seems fine. I can see some `[anon]`blocks grow in size, nothing significant regarding the number of blocks.

I'm quite desperate with that problem since I do not know where to look now, I've ran out of idea.

a screendump of jvisualvm : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/598264jvisualvm.png

Any idea?

Comment: Not releasing SWT resources like images, colors, fonts, .... would be a first guess.

Comment: Java Monitor on Eclipse shows a constant number of SWT resources. Even though, could it explain the leak only happening on Linux ?

Comment: SWT code is completely different on each platform, so failure to close resources has different consequences on each platform.

Comment: Checked a second time, SWT resources are OK

Comment: Updating the SWT library made the memory grow slower. Does it mean something?